# check if a String is already in a LinkedHashMap (as a value)

Tags: java, string, duplicates, treemap

I'd like to check if the value of a `LinkedHashmap` already contains a String, and if not, add it to the ArrayList.
`windowSize` is between 1 and 7 (predefined)

```
String wholeString = "HausA HausB";

final Map<String, ArrayList<String>> generateMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
final int limit = wholeString.length() - windowSize;
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        String first = wholeString.substring(i, i + windowSize);
        String second = wholeString.substring(i + windowSize, i
                + windowSize + 1);

        int endKey = i + windowSize;
        if (!generateMap.containsKey(first)) {
            generateMap.put(wholeString.substring(i, endKey),
                    new ArrayList<String>());
        }
                    //check here if the String 'second' is already mapped to the key'
                    if (i < limit && !generateMap.get(first).equals(second)) {
            generateMap.get(first).add(second);
        } else {
            generateMap.get(first).add(null);
        }
    }

   for (Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> e : generateMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(e.getKey() + " -> " + e.getValue()+ "\n");
   }
```

The Output now:

```
HausA -> [ ]
ausA  -> [H]
usA H -> [a]
sA Ha -> [u]
A Hau -> [s]
Haus  -> [B]
HausB -> [ ]
```

How it should be:

```
HausA -> [ ]
ausA  -> [H]
usA H -> [a]
sA Ha -> [u]
A Hau -> [s]
Haus  -> [A,B] //<---
HausB -> [ ]
```

Thank you for your appreciated help.

Comment: See: [Stack Overflow is not going to read all that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129787/172496)

Comment: You should **really** think about using a [Guava Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html). @BrianRoach eh, that's really not that much code.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL But there is no real description of what this is supposed to do. Sure, there is the desired output, but with code that complicated, some reasoning why this should be the output would help.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL - it's more the problem of "Here's my broken code, please fix it"

Comment: I commented the important part of the code
@MДΓΓБДLL:    I must not use Guava..

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger to see what's happening in the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See how this fits...

```
final String wholeString = " HausA HausB";
final Map<String, Set<String>> generateMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Set<String>>();
final int windowSize = 5;

final int limit = wholeString.length() - windowSize;
for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
  final int endKey = i + windowSize;
  final String
      first = wholeString.substring(i, endKey),
      second = wholeString.substring(endKey, endKey + 1);
  if (!generateMap.containsKey(first))
    generateMap.put(first, new HashSet<String>());
  generateMap.get(first).add(second);
}

for (Entry<String, Set<String>> e : generateMap.entrySet()) {
  System.out.println(e.getKey() + " -> " + e.getValue());
}
```